# CVS Memory Allocation Error

Tags: memory, cvs

Running `cvs up -Ad`, I'm getting the following error thrown:

`cvs [update aborted]: out of memory; can not allocate 333685120 bytes`

But upon investigation, (running `top`), there appears to be enough free memory after all.

`Mem:   1025528k total,   521660k used,   503868k free,    48736k buffers`

Does anyone know of any common CVS issues that might cause this error to be thrown as something of a red herring?  If memory isn't the real problem, any ideas as to what I can do to find out what is?

Answer (score 0):

There are at least 3 solutions for this bug:

A) Uninstall CVSNT, then install CVSNT-x64. Because this bug is already fixed in 64-bit version of CVSNT.

B) Fix this bug in your currently installed (32-bit) cvs.exe binary by using editbin.exe tool from Visual Studio distribution. Use this command:

```
editbin.exe /LARGEADDRESSAWARE cvs.exe
```

C) If you can't reinstall or modify your CVSNT, then as a temporary solution, try updating separate sub-folders and/or separate files in the folder you are trying to update, one-by-one, to make CVSNT allocate less memory.